# Issue with pushing a Struct object into queue

Tags: c++

I have a structure and I want to create a queue of this struct. I have a problem with pushing a new element. Help please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
Node *left, *right;
int key;
};

queue<Node> q;

void updateLevel( Node &n, int &level){
if(n.left!=NULL && n.right!=NULL){
    level+=2;
    q.push(n.left);
    q.push(n.right);
    }
    else if(n.left!=NULL || n.right!=NULL){
    level++;
    if(n.left!=NULL) q.push(n.left);
    if(n.right!=NULL) q.push(n.right);
}
};
void printTree(Node root){
//if(root!=NULL){
    q.push(root);
    Node n;
    while(!q.empty()){
        n =q.pop();
        updateLevel(n,nextLevel);
        curLevel--;
        cout<<n.key;
        if(curLevel<=0){
            cout<<endl;
            curLevel=nextLevel;
            nextLevel=0;
        }

    }

//}
    };

   int main() {

Node rootTree;

printTree(rootTree);

return 0;
```

}

I am calling this function from the main. I also have got an error with checking in the if condition about NULL. Help please

Comment: You're pushing `Node*` into your `Node` queue.

Comment: @WhozCraig how? I am sending Node &n to be by reference

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy n is Node&, but n.left and n.right are not.

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve this? @tacp

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy would you please show more codes and specific error message such that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: @tacp here is the whole problem

Comment: I am a Java developer and in Java we don`t handle the pointer and sending by reference

Answer (score 1):

At least one error here:

```
queue<Node> q; //a queue of Node
```

however:

```
q.push(n.left);
q.push(n.right); //n.left and n.right are Node*.
```

You are pushing `Node*` to a queue accepts `Node`.

You may have other errors, but from the code you have shown, this is at least one of them.

**EDIT**: based on you updated code.

```
Node rootTree;
```

you did not define any constructor in your `Node`, so  members of `rootTree` are not initialized. `left` and `right` are not `NULL` to start with. therefore, it is useless for you to  check for `NULL` on them.

```
updateLevel(n,nextLevel);
```

what is `nextLevel`, seems not defined.

Try to set up some breakpoints in the code and locate the problem. The error says `if condition check` has problem, but it is  likely that root cause may be somewhere else.

Comment: What about the problem with (n.left!= NULL )?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy what's wrong with `(n.left != NULL)`? mind showing more code and specific error message?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy I am sorry, I have done my best to figure out as much errors as I can.

Comment: I am completely satisfied with Java but it is an assignment in collage :D .. Thank you again

Comment: Also, if it helps: 'a reference to a Node' allows you to refer to a Node by another name.  That is what 'alias' means. Understand? Or, you can think of a reference as a constant pointer, i.e. the pointer points to one place in memory, and the pointer cannot be moved to point to another place in memory.   However, the value at that place in memory can change.